# Функция не удаляет блоки

Tags: javascript

Начал практиковаться написанием кода на JavaScript и (как это обычно) Я столкнулся с проблемой:

Я решил написать код, позволяющий интерактивно удалять блоки. Проблема с функцией `toClose`, она не удаляет класс `.overlay--showed`. Где здесь написано неправильно?

```js
const toShow = (elemToClick, elemToOpen, classToAdd) => {
  elemToClick = document.querySelectorAll(elemToClick);
  elemToOpen = document.querySelector(elemToOpen);

  for (let i = 0; i < elemToClick.length; i++) {
    this.onclick = () => {
      elemToOpen.classList.add(classToAdd);
    };
  }
};

const toClose = (elemToClick, elemToClose, classToRemove) => {
  elemToClick = document.querySelector(elemToClick);
  elemToClose = document.querySelector(elemToClose);

  elemToClick.onclick = () => {
    if (elemToClose.classList.contains(classToRemove)) {
      elemToClose.classList.remove(classToRemove);
      console.log(elemToClose);
      console.log(elemToClick);
    }
  };
};

toShow("#openModal", ".overlay", "overlay--showed");
toClose("#closeModal", ".overlay", "overlay--showed"); // Эта функция не удаляет класс...
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.overlay--showed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__item_title"><strong>Delete me</strong></div>
    <div class="button" id="openModal"><i class="button__icon fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay__modal"></div>
    <div class="button" id="closeModal"><i class="button__icon fas fa-times"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вызов `console.log(elemToClose);` происходит?

Comment: почему в `toShow` у вас клик на `this` накладывается? Там ведь `this` на глобальный объект `window` ссылается

Comment: Я исправлю все это. Помогите разобраться с нужной функцией.  В консоли все правильно выводится.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неопытность. Все понял, приму это за урок!

Answer (score 1):

Вам не зря в комментариях @ThisMan писал об ошибке с `this` в функции `toShow`. Если бы вы к нему прислушались и исправили все это, то ошибку бы сами нашли.

Ошибка была в присваивании обработчика события `click` на элемент `windows`, а не на вашу кнопку открытия.

Пример:

```js
const toShow = (elemToClick, elemToOpen, classToAdd) => {
  elemToClick = document.querySelectorAll(elemToClick);
  elemToOpen = document.querySelector(elemToOpen);

  for (let i = 0; i < elemToClick.length; i++) {
    elemToClick[0].onclick = () => { // Здесь была ошибка
      elemToOpen.classList.add(classToAdd);
    };
  }
};

const toClose = (elemToClick, elemToClose, classToRemove) => {
  elemToClick = document.querySelector(elemToClick);
  elemToClose = document.querySelector(elemToClose);

  elemToClick.onclick = () => {
    if (elemToClose.classList.contains(classToRemove)) {
      event.prevent
      elemToClose.classList.remove(classToRemove);
      console.log(elemToClose);
      console.log(elemToClick);
    }
  };
};

toShow("#openModal", ".overlay", "overlay--showed");
toClose("#closeModal", ".overlay", "overlay--showed"); // Эта функция не удаляет класс...
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.overlay--showed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item">
    <div class="container__item_title"><strong>Delete me</strong></div>
    <div class="button" id="openModal"><i class="button__icon fas fa-ellipsis-v">open</i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="overlay__modal"></div>
    <div class="button" id="closeModal"><i class="button__icon fas fa-times">close</i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Приму все это на будущее, еще раз Спасибо!

Comment: @АндрейДобрин благодарность принимается в виде принятого ответа (синяя галочка напротив ответа)